# How does synced shot work online?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

A friend and I have been trying to do a synced shot online by each marking a target in our field of view (clear shot) and holding down A to start it but nothing happens.  Can we do a synced shot online? If so, how?

[So far we have been marking enemies with synced shot, verbally starting the 'synced shot', and then manually shooting our assigned target]

Comment: The way you are currently doing it is the way it works as I understand it. That's what my friends and I do. As there are no AI players to take the 'other' shots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synced shot doesn't work that way online. Online it's just a fancy way of calling out targets and decide who will do which. You still have to take the shot. There are no AI players who take the shot for you.